# root.after causes Tkinter application to stop working

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

```
    def colision(self):
        if self.coords(self.bola)[1]<50:
            self.boladir=1
        if self.coords(self.bola)[1]>870:
            self.jugando=0
            self.pierde()
#        ladrillos=self.find_withtag("brick")

    def mueve_bola(self):
        if self.jugando:
            if self.boladir==0:
                    self.move(self.bola,0,-10)
            elif self.boladir==1:
                    self.move(self.bola,0,10)
        self.colision()
        root.after(velocidad_bola,self.mueve_bola)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colision` calls itself via `after`, so when the game starts this will be called every 20 ms. `mueve_bola also calls itself every 20ms. However,`mueve_bola`_also_ calls`colision`. So, every 20ms,`colision`creates another unending stream of calls to itself every 20ms. 20 ms later`mueve_bola`calls`colision`again, which again starts another stream of calls every 20ms. After just one second`colision`is being called 50 times every 20ms. After two seconds it will be 100 calls to`colision`every 20 ms. Do you see the problem? In very little time you will have millions of calls to`colision` every second.

You only need to calculate collisions when you move things, so there is no need to have `colision` call itself every 20ms. It's only necessary to call it once each time you update the display.

I recommend you create a single method that is called every 40ms or so. in it you can adjust the coordinates of everything at once. update the coordinates of the rows,  then the player's paddle, then the ball, and then check for collisions.

Comment: Great!!! Yes, now I see the humongous mistake I made ^^ you're absolutely right!! I'll try to do as you say: a single method to move everything will be much more simple to implement... Thanks!!